# Comparar y Validar "Hashing" en Python

Tags: python, hash, blockchain

Estoy intentando escribir un programa para votar en python utilizando la tecnología python. Hasta este punto, este es mi código:

```
import datetime
from hashlib import sha256
import os

nameprogression = 0
blockNo = 0

localread = []
externalread = []


def initiate():
    try:
         os.mkdir('blockchain')
         os.chdir('blockchain')
    except:
        os.chdir('blockchain')

    global nameprogression
    nameprogression = nameprogression + 1
    name = "{}.xvote".format(str(nameprogression))

    with open(name, mode='w+') as f:

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        f.write('genesis_block {}'.format(str(timestamp)))

        #This section reads and hashes the data on the file.
        f.seek(0)
        data = f.read().encode('utf-8')
        h = sha256(data)
        f.write(str('\n' + h.hexdigest()))

        global localread
        localread = str('\n' + h.hexdigest())

def validate():

    name = "{}.xvote".format(str(nameprogression))

    with open(name, mode='r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        data = data[1]
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        h = sha256(data)

        global externalread
        externalread = str('\n' + h.hexdigest())

def compare():
    print(localread)
    print(externalread)

initiate()

validate()

compare()
```

Básicamente, este programa me está generando un archivo en un folder con un información de la cual consigo un hash y se lo agrego al archivo. Y para el bloque de cadena que quiero implementar en este código debo de poder validar de algún modo desde un programa externo que ese hash corresponde a la información en el archivo. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto este programa que me imprime la hash generada junto con el archivo y la hash calculada para validar la primera, recibo dos hashes diferentes.

Creo que estoy procediendo con la misma táctica de encriptación en ambas funciones. Hasta he intentado imprimir las 'strings' que cada función recupera del archivo para ver si coincidian antes de hashearlas, y creo que si coincidían. La única diferencia que noté cuando imprimí las 'strings' es que una empezaba con " b' " y la otra sin la 'b' al principio.

La verdad no sé como puedo lograr validar la hash con mi código, dado que ya he intentado varias cosas. Agradezco de antemano su ayuda para resolver mi problema.
Gracias, 
Diego Hernández.
Python Amatheur.

Answer (score 1):

2 problemas:

- estás obteniendo la segunda línea, en lugar de la primera
- Estás ocupando también el símbolo de nueva línea

Cambia la función por lo siguiente:

```
def validate():

    name = "{}.xvote".format(str(nameprogression))

    with open(name, mode='r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        data = data[0]   # read the first line
        data = data[:-1]  # remove the '\n'
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        h = sha256(data) 

        global externalread
        externalread = str('\n' + h.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Probé su código y funcionó perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias por su tiempo y apoyo.

Comment: Hola Diego, no hay problema. Bienvenido a Stack overflow. Ahora, lo típico dentro de SO es que se acepte la respuesta que solucione el problema.